# Controlling my wireless card, how do I know if I will harm it?

Tags: networking, 16.04

I was looking for a solution for increasing my wifi signal, my laptop have a 10$ web card so I can't expect too much, my device is [Qualcomm Atheros AR9485](https://www.cnet.com/products/atheros-ar9485-802-11-b-g-n-wifi-adapter-1x1-network-adapter-series/specs/) in some page, they told me that the command `sudo iwconfig wlan0 txpower 20`  will be enough to control that signal and it works like a charm but, I'm not sure if is secure using it.

I also checked out the [iwconfig manual](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/iwconfig8.html) but it seems like is for electronic engineers so I can't understand it at all, so my questions are simple.

`txpower` in what scale works(1-100? 1-1000)?, how much power do I need for reaching my router? (is 3 rooms away from me), my web card will melt? According to my web card specs, what is the recommended `txpower` signal for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upping your Tx power will have no effect on the Rx signal strength. You would need to increase the Tx power **on the router** to get a stronger signal on your laptop.

Unless you are using some Kali tools to break into other Wi-Fi networks (I hope not), there isn't really much point in upping the Tx power in your laptop.

Also, keep in mind that increasing the Tx power will generate more heat, and also degrade the quality of the transmitted signal.

Comment: I'm sure the problem is my laptop, because even my low-spec phone can reach the signal outside house, but my laptop can't. I use txpower for increasing that and works well, but I'm not sure if I should keep that conf, I have an external cooler fan for my laptop btw

Comment: @RenatoA. - Maybe your laptop has a defective antenna. But, increasing the Tx power on your laptop will not allow you to receive the signal from the router any better.

Comment: ok, i'll set txpower to auto =(